# Search a positive gradient in a dynamic-sized 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, typeerror

I need to search a positive & negative gradient in a 2d array for values, for example.

Positive gradient: bottom left > middle > top right

Negative gradient: top left > middle > bottom right

```
[
    ['x',  'x',  'o'],
    [null, null, 'o'],
    ['x', 'x',   null] 
]
```

I have 2 functions. First the value is found in a for loop, when found both of these functions run to search the positive & negative gradient of the maze and return true if a winning combination is found.

scanForNegativeGradientCombinationsworks, scanForPositiveGradientCombinations does not and ends in a typeError. I think the problem may be when reducing the rowIndex, I am pushing the game out of bounds, but im not sure.

```
const isDiagonalWinner = (rowCellValues, winCountCondition, player) => {

for(let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCellValues.length; rowIndex++){
    for(let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < rowCellValues[rowIndex].length; columnIndex++){
        const cellValue = rowCellValues[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        if(cellValue === player.symbol) {
            console.log('initiating player scan for ', player.symbol, 'at', [rowIndex, columnIndex]);
            if(scanForNegativeGradientCombinations(columnIndex, rowIndex, rowCellValues, player.symbol, winCountCondition)) {
                return true
            } 

            if(scanForPositiveGradientCombinations(columnIndex, rowIndex, rowCellValues, player.symbol, winCountCondition)) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}

return null;
};
```

Above is the function that will call the following 2 functions.

```
const scanForNegativeGradientCombinations= (columnIndex, rowIndex, rowCellValues, playerSymbol, winCountCondition) => {
let counter = 0;
while(rowIndex < rowCellValues.length && columnIndex < rowCellValues[rowIndex].length){
    if(rowCellValues[rowIndex][columnIndex] === playerSymbol){
        counter++;
    }
    if(counter >= winCountCondition){
        return true;
    }
    rowIndex++;
    columnIndex++;
}
return false;
}


const scanForPositiveGradientCombinations= (columnIndex, rowIndex, rowCellValues, playerSymbol, winCountCondition) => {
let counter = 0;
while(rowIndex < rowCellValues.length && columnIndex < rowCellValues[rowIndex].length){
    if(rowCellValues[rowIndex][columnIndex] === playerSymbol){
        counter++;
    }
    if(counter >= winCountCondition){
        return true;
    }
    rowIndex--;
    columnIndex++;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: You've not explained what a positive/negative gradient means

Comment: @AndrewParks thanks for the feedback. Hopefully that makes it clearer

Comment: You've still not explained how to get from seeing x/o/null values to determining if there is a positive or negative gradient

Comment: @AndrewParks I'm not sure I understand your feedback sorry! there should always be a pos/neg gradient if there is more than 1 row & column. im trying to search gradients(slopes) for winning combinations ( 3 in a row in this case )

Comment: You've not explained the rules for looking at an array and determining whether the array has a positive or negative gradient. For example, if it's full of only null values, is that a positive or negative gradient? Is this a game of tic-tac-toe? Do you just want to detect the presence of a diagonal line? And if there is no fully formed diagonal line, is there no "gradient"? Can there be other things in the array, like other numbers or letters?

Comment: @AndrewParks yeah for a game of tic-tac-toe, I was trying to avoid that wording because I was getting hard-coded answers. I'm trying to make it work regardless of how big the game board. 

I think my wording of "gradient" was poor. I meant a positive gradient = a slope that goes up, and a negative gradient = a slope that goes down. I'll try and rethink my wording to make this question make more sense. thanks

Comment: is it always a 3x3 array?

Comment: @AndrewParks it will always be square(equal dimensions) but can be any size

Comment: OK, i've updated my answer to allow for any board size. I'm not sure why your code is so complicated when all it has to do is check the diagonal

Comment: @AndrewParks thanks a lot, ill try to implement this. Im very new to coding, learning for about 4 months. It could explain the funny code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function sequence(n) { return Array(n).fill().map((_,i)=>i) }

function diagonalWin(board) {
  let d = board.length
  let seq = sequence(d)
  return board[0][0]!==null && seq.every(i=>board[i][i]===board[0][0]) ||
  board[0][d-1]!==null && seq.every(i=>board[i][d-i-1]===board[0][d-1])
}

console.log(diagonalWin([
  ['x',  'x',  'o'],
  [null, null, 'o'],
  ['x', 'x',   null]
]))

console.log(diagonalWin([
  ['x',  'x',  'o'],
  [null, 'x', 'o'],
  ['x', 'x',  'x']
]))

console.log(diagonalWin([
  ['x',  'x',  'o'],
  [null, 'o', 'o'],
  ['o', 'x',  'x']
]))
```